# Связь многие ко многим, может ли быть 2 промежуточные таблицы между ними?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, relation

Собственно вопрос, может ли быть у связи многие ко многим две промежуточные таблицы? Например, пациенты и доктора, между ними таблицы запись и диагноз.

Comment: приведите конкретику, что вы имеете в виду под "двумя таблицами между". прям описание структуры. и формальное текстовое описание, как эти объекты реального мира по факту связаны со всеми нюансами

Comment: *Например, пациенты и доктора, между ними таблицы запись и диагноз.* Хочу огорчить - сущности Пациент и Доктор полностью независимы. Хотя и могут являться экземплярами одной и той же сущности Человек.